# xConnect error in 9.1: One or more local models conflict with the xDB service layer

Tags: xconnect, contact-facets

I've added a custom facet and model, serialized the model and deployed it to my xConnect server to the two locations outlined in Sitecore's documentation but I'm still seeing this error. Because of the error the site cannot start the tracker so I'm unable to record any interactions about users.

I'm running 9.1 locally using the Standalone role.

Model

```
public class AgentInfoModel
{
    public static XdbModel Model { get; } = AgentInfoModel.BuildModel();

    private static XdbModel BuildModel()
    {
        XdbModelBuilder modelBuilder = new XdbModelBuilder("AgentInfoModel", new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));

        modelBuilder.DefineFacet<Contact, ContactAgentInfo>(ContactAgentInfo.DefaultFacetKey);
        modelBuilder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);

        return modelBuilder.BuildModel();
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
"Name": "ContactAgentInfo",
"Version": "1.0",
"References": [
{
  "Name": "XConnect",
  "Version": "1.0"
}
],
"Types": {
"USCM.Foundation.Agency.Facets.ContactAgentInfo": {
  "Type": "Facet",
  "BaseType": "Sitecore.XConnect.Facet",
  "ClrType": "USCM.Foundation.Agency.Facets.ContactAgentInfo, USCM.Foundation.Agency.Facets, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
  "Properties": {
    "UserID": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "HideSplashContent": {
      "Type": "Boolean"
    },
    "HideSplashContentStatus": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "LastVisitedDateUTC": {
      "Type": "DateTime"
    },
    "RefreshDateUTC": {
      "Type": "DateTime"
    },
    "AgentState": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "DPecID": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "DPecUserType": {
      "Type": "String"
    }
  }
}
},
"Facets": [
{
  "Target": "Contact",
  "Name": "ContactAgentInfo",
  "Type": "USCM.Foundation.Agency.Facets.ContactAgentInfo"
}
]
```

Error:

> Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XdbModelConflictException
>   Message: One or more local models conflict with the xDB service layer.
>    'AgentInfoModel, 1.0' does not have a remote version

Comment: Can you post your model and your json file contents.

Comment: And please do not forget to post the error message you are getting.

Comment: Try remove the line modelBuilder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);

Comment: Also triple check you've followed the deployment instructions correctly. It needs to go in your standalone instance and the json needs to go in two different places on your xconnect instance. Lastly you need an xml config for your marketing automation service.

Comment: @MarkGibbons: in addition to the changing the name, your advice to remove the ReferenceModel also was important. I had created the json manually and neglected to add the reference to CollectionModel.Model in the json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model builder is making a model named `"AgentInfoModel"`. But the JSON you posted is for a model called `"ContactAgentInfo"`. The Name field of you JSON should match the name and version you specified on the XdbModelBuilder class.

I believe you may have renamed your model at some point and forgot to regenerated your json model.

**This**

```
XdbModelBuilder("AgentInfoModel", new XdbModelVersion(1, 0))
```

**Does not match this:**

```
{
   "Name": "ContactAgentInfo",
   "Version": "1.0",
   "References": [
   {
      "Name": "XConnect",
      "Version": "1.0"
   }
}
```

One last thing, you mentioned logging user interactions. When you want to use your facet for interactions, you need to define your facet as an `Interaction` facet in the builder. Your facet is currently defined as a Contact facet.

````
modelBuilder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);

modelBuilder.DefineFacet<Interaction, ContactAgentInfo>(ContactAgentInfo.DefaultFacetKey);```
````

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late for this reply, but wanted to share one more aspect, I'm sure will be useful to others, I got the same error on Sitecore version 9.1

**The error logs was as below**  -

> 5868 15:38:17 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/pathAnalyzerLiveAgent
>   Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XdbModelConflictException
>   Message: One or more local models conflict with the xDB service layer.
>    'SelectedVehicleModel, 1.0' does not match the remote version
>   Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.XConnect.DefaultXdbContextFactory.CreateReadOnly()
>      at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

**Solution**

I've my deployment project for the xConnect. Whenever I do any change it will generate the model and update the model to xConnect model repository, Recently I've changed the path of that project, so My model was not updating at the right place.
I did a change in Model class and generated, but it didn't update at the root folder (xconnect\App_Data\Models).
To fix that I've regenerated the model and update to xConnect root path.
I hope that will help others.